# TeamCity - prefer cleaning up artifacts cache rather than checkout directories, when using free disk space build feature

Tags: teamcity

I have a project with two branches which I have set up to check out to different directories. This is because each branch has expensive-to-create intermediate files, and uses a different version of a build tool, so I need to keep them separate.

I have many configurations with the free disk space build feature.

I keep finding that when a build agent needs to free some space, it chooses to delete the checkout directory from the other branch, which then results in a lengthy clean checkout, and full rebuild of the project, next time a build is run on that branch.

The agents also have a large number of large artifacts in their artifacts cache, which I think it would be much more preferable to delete.

If it's useful information - the checkout directory of one of the branches may only be used once a day, or every 2 days. The artifacts cache contains perhaps 20-40 artifacts, from one day alone - it is updated much more frequently.

I would prefer not to disable artifact caching altogether, since these artifacts are often used by multiple builds on the same agent.

Ideally I think what I am looking for is some kind of configuration parameter to tell TeamCity how I would like to weight deleting artifacts compared to deleting checkout directories, or some parameters for minimum age of artifacts or checkout directories, to be considered for deletion. Does this exist? I can't see anything like this in the web interface.